# How best to avoid member implementation of class' Abstract/Interface instance variables

Tags: java, dependency-injection, generics, dependency-inversion

I'm sorry if the phrasing of the question is a bit unclear but let me try to clarify below. (If anyone can word it better, feel free to edit)

I have a `Map` instance variable, `groups`, which is defined as follows with the given type parameters:

```
Map<Group, Map<Username, GroupMember>> groups
```

Within the same enclosing class, I have a public method, `addGroup(Group group)`, which is supposed to put a new entry into the `groups` map. The `Group` object contains all the relevant information for the entry.

The conundrum here stems from the fact that adding a new element to `groups` would require that I specify a concrete object for `Map<Username, GroupMember>` value within `addGroup()`, thus internally coupling the abstraction with an implementation--clearly in violation of the dependency inversion principle.

My question is then how do I avert this problem? I hesitate delegating the responsibility of defining the object to the caller (i.e. defining the method as `addGroup(Group group, Map<Username, GroupMember> groupMembers)` for instance) as it chips away at abstraction, may be inconsistent with the constructor injected implementation; and in my opinion, introduces unnecessary coupling with the class implementation details. Perhaps I should reconsider my design.

---

**EDIT**

Here's where the problem is coming from:

```
public class Foo {

    private final Map<Group, Map<Username, GroupMember>> groups;

    //...

    public void addGroup(Group group) {
            if (exists(group))
                throw new IllegalOperationException("Group with same name already exists");
            //Declaring a new HashMap within the class (i.e. defining the implementation within a class member)
            groups.put(group, new HashMap<Username, GroupMember>(Map evaluation based on group object)));
    }

    //...
}
```

Here's what I'm hesitant of doing:

```
//Passing Map<Username, GroupMember> object decreases abstraction and exposes implementation details
public void addGroup(Group group, Map<Username, GroupMember> groupMembers) {
        if (exists(group))
            throw new IllegalOperationException("Group with same name already exists");
        groups.put(group, groupMembers));
}
```

Here's part of the definition for `Group` to further add context;

```
public class Group {

    private final String name;
    private final String description;
    private final Instant dateCreated;
    private final Collection<GroupMember> members;

    //... Constructor and getters for the fields
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you're hesitant about allowing the caller to specify it, since it sounds like the caller will be the one using it. Perhaps a short code example of the class and its usage would clarify things.

Comment: @bitsoflogic I made some edits, hope they can better clarify what I mean

Comment: You want to keep the `Map<Username, GroupMember>` collection dynamic, but also hidden from the callers.  What's the value of it being dynamic if the callers are not aware of it?

Comment: @bitsoflogic The `Map<Username, GroupMember>` is supposed to be relevant only to the Composition Root and not the caller (hence `addGroup(Group group)`)

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a Dependency Inversion violation because the callers don't need to pass in the `Map<Username, GroupMember>`.  So, simply implementing `new HashMap` internally is fine.  If it ever needs to change, the callers will never know nor be impacted by the change.  The Dependency Inversion violation is really that you're using `addGroup(Group)` instead of `addGroup(IGroup)`.  Whether or not that violation is worth changing is up for debate - it's not a rule I advocate following 100%.

Comment: You could also provide a factory in the caller, using a method like `computeIfAbsent()`

Comment: Why is `Foo` in charge of associating _usernames_ to _group members_? Shouldn't that be a responsibility of a `Group`?

Comment: @Marco, it indeed is the responsibility of the `GroupMember` rather and not `Foo` (`Username` is a property of `GroupMember`). I only used a `Map` to salvage the O(1) access time otherwise the Map would have been something like `Map<Group, Collection<GroupMember>>`

Answer (score 1):

**Dependency Inversion Principle(DIP)** is ignoring dependencies from *Low Level* to *High Level*.

In your case, your `addGroup(Group group)` method has dependency to `Group` class. You can create an `IGroup` interface and implement it to `Group` class. Then convert your method like `addGroup(IGroup group)`. Now your business doesn't depend concrete class from *Low Level*.

> I hesitate delegating the responsibility of defining the object to the caller (i.e. defining the method as addGroup(Group group, Map groupMembers) for instance) as it chips away at abstraction, may be inconsistent with the constructor injected implementation; and in my opinion, introduces unnecessary coupling with the class implementation details.

We are creating many methods and calling within any other methods from library or framework. Those methods don't require(depend) their inner requirements as parameters.

In your case, you are able to do mapping(I assume its your business) in your `addGroup(Group group)` method without depending any other thing from caller. So, you don't need to create `public void addGroup(Group group, Map<Username, GroupMember> groupMembers)` method for **DIP** but you should use `IUsername` and `IGroupMember` instead of `Username` and `GroupMember` in `addGroup(IGroup group)`.

Comment: What does "Those methods don't wait their inner needed as parameters." mean?

Comment: @PeteKirkham I tried to use more proper words. I hope it is more clear now.

Answer (score 1):

Let me do a step back to get a look at the bigger picture.

You seem to have a requirement to map from `Username` to `GroupMember` instances inside a `Group`, and the `Group` instance seems to carry all information necessary for that mapping.

If that's correct, you should not expose a method signature that allows your caller to establish an incorrect association, so the `addGroup(Group group, Map<Username, GroupMember> groupMembers)` would be a bad idea, inviting for mis-use.

The fact that you create this `Map<Group, Map<Username, GroupMember>> groups` field implies to me that you have a method like

```
public GroupMember describeUser(Group group, Username user) { ... }
```

As this will only deal with things that are conceptually internals of `Group` instances, what about moving this functionality from the `Foo` into the `Group` class, maintaining a simpler `Map` there if access speed is really that important?